# grep only for certain word on line

Tags: linux, text-editor, server-side-scripting

Need to grep only the word between the 2nd and 3rd to last /

This is shown in the extract below, to note that the location on the filename is not always the same counting from the front. Any ideas would be helpful.

/home/user/Drive-backup/2010 Backup/2010 Account/Jan/usernameneedtogrep/user.dir/4.txt

Comment: Do you want a script or a command in an editor (which one?) ?

Comment: @M42 a script would be better thanks

Comment: could you show the exact result you're looking for ?

Comment: @M42 from the above line I just need the username which is located between to the second and third to last / to be outputted to a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use `awk`:

```
awk -F/ '{print $(NF-2)}'
```

- splits on `/`
- `NF` is the index of the last column, `$NF` the last column itself and `$(NF-2)` the 3rd-to-last column.

You might of course first need to filter out lines in your input that are not paths (e.g. using `grep` and then piping to `awk`)

Comment: If I wanted to get the 3rd column as well would that be another AWK command next to it or before it

Comment: This would print the 3rd and the 3rd-to-last column: `awk -F/ '{print $3, $(NF-2)}'`. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Perl script that does the job:

```
my $str = q!/home/user/Drive-backup/2010 Backup/2010 Account/Jan/usernameneedtogrep/user.dir/4.txt!;
my $res = (split('/',$str))[-3];
print $res;
```

**output:**

```
usernameneedtogrep
```

Answer (score 0):

a regular expression something like this should do the trick:

```
/.\/(.+?)\/.*?\/.*$/
```

(note I'm using lazy searches (`+?` and `*?`) so that it doesn't includes slashes where we don't want it to)